# How to ask investment for one saas product of many?

Tags: investing, banking, investment-strategies, corporation, start-up

I have a company that will have many saas products under it . For now if I ask investment, do I have to offer equity of company just for that one product? Is there a way I can offer equity of just that one product?

Comment: Before going through the hassle of separating these businesses from each other, find out if investors have any interest in such offerings. Financiars will walk away quickly if they think the deal is fragile (does this separate entity actually rely on operations from other businesses you've striped it away from) or you're hoarding a cash cow that belongs in the portfolio. Both of these seem like likely scenarios they'll envision simply from seeing this activity in your corporate history.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "*Question about small business that have no bearing on personal finance*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want equity for just one product, then you should consider putting that product into a new company.

You can offer fractional ownership of just one product, but the complexity and liability issues are reasons why people don't do it that way. Putting the product into a new entity, which needs capital, is the effective way of doing the same thing.